# How can I use ERC with an IRC offered over SSL?

Tags: erc, gnutls, ssl

I'm trying to connect to Gitter's IRC servers to join the chat room `vermiculus/stack-mode`, but according to Gitter, [they offer this service over SSL](https://irc.gitter.im):

```
      _                 _ _   _            _           
     (_)_ __ ___   __ _(_) |_| |_ ___ _ __(_)_ __ ___  
     | | '__/ __| / _` | | __| __/ _ \ '__| | '_ ` _ \ 
     | | | | (__ | (_| | | |_| ||  __/ |_ | | | | | | |
     |_|_|  \___(_)__, |_|\__|\__\___|_(_)|_|_| |_| |_|
                  |___/                                

"Life is really simple, and so is to use Gitter IRC" - Confucius
what is Gitter?

man irc.gitter.im (this service is still very much beta)
1. Connect to irc.gitter.im with your IRC client using SSL
2. /PASS <my token has been redacted for obvious reasons>
3. /NICK vermiculus
4. Profit

100% compatible with Lynx. Seriously.
```

However, I cannot find any mention of SSL in ERC's Info manual.  How can I specify that the connection should be secure?  I believe this is the reason I receive the error:

```
[Sun Nov 23 2014]


Connection failed!  Re-establishing connection...               [23:21]



[Sun Nov 23 2014]
ERC> /join vermiculus/stack-mode                                [23:22]
ERC> /join vermiculus/stack-mode


Connection failed!  Re-establishing connection...



[Sun Nov 23 2014]


Connection failed!  Re-establishing connection...               [23:23]



[Sun Nov 23 2014]
ERC> /PASS <again, redacted>                                    [23:23]
ERC> /NICK vermiculus


Connection failed!  Re-establishing connection...               [23:24]



[Sun Nov 23 2014]


Connection failed!  Re-establishing connection...               [23:24]


ERC>
```

Comment: I tagged this question as [tag:gnutls] because it will likely be used in the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However, I cannot find any mention of SSL in ERC's Info manual.

I've found a mention of SSL [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ErcSSL)

> How can I specify that the connection should be secure?

What about `M-x erc-tls` ?

Comment: I guess I just wasn't searching for the right thing :)

Answer (score 8):

Testing it this morning:

```
(require 'erc)
(erc-tls :server "irc.gitter.im" :port 6667) ;; M-x erc-tls -> irc.gitter.im -> accept default PORT.
```

Then when prompted:

```
NICK: jleechpe
PASS: <redacted>

/join #vermiculus/stack-mode
```

Comment: Are we on different erc versions? My `erc` command only accepts keyword arguments.

Comment: Oops.  That would be my mistake because of just using prompts.  Fixing